# Gradle eclipse task adds unnecessary test sources to Web Deployment Assembly in Spring Source Tools

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am getting in trouble with Spring Tool Suite Eclipse and Gradle. When I run "eclipse" task, it modify my Web Deployment Assembly (WDA) as shown on picture.

[image: Depoyment Assembly after gradle eclipse task]

Last tree items in WDA (not in screen, they are in bottom of list) are correcly set sources:

```
src/main/java | WEB-INF/classes
src/main/resources | WEB-INF/classes
src/main/webapp | /
```

but all these folder sources as you can see on screen are wrong. I cant start application because it try create beans from test config. Everytime i have to delete them manually and it waste my time.

How can I solve this behaviour?

I dont know if there is trouble somewhere in definition, that the deploy path is WEB-INF/classes (and if so, how to make it corretly) or if problem is in adding these folders to WDA. I can`t find where is this behaviour defined.

Or is possible to remove them with gradle in eclipse task? I cant figure out where is this stored in eclipse and if I can manipulate with it.

Comment: It seem that problem is with wtp eclispe plugin. There is quite similar question: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/wtp_eclipse_plugin_wb_resources_not_generated_correctly_when_using_task_eclipse

Answer (score 1):

I ended with this hack. It manipulates with **.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component** file and removes all nodes whose source starts with "/src/"

```
eclipse.wtp.component {  
    file.withXml { xml ->       
            def node = xml.asNode()                     
            def wbrNodes = node.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'wb-resource' && it.'@source-path'.startsWith("/src/")}

            if (wbrNodes.size() > 0) {
                    wbrNodes.each { n -> n.parent().remove(n) }
            }                   
    }
```

}

Comment: Same works for my project. Thanks for publishing this script!

Answer (score 0):

I've found Gradle's eclipse and eclipseWtp task to do a pretty bad job of generating the Eclipse project configuration and they don't seem to update them to keep up with WTP changes. So instead I install the Gradle plugins for Eclipse (part of Spring Tool Suite) and then manually configure the project after running gradle eclipse one time. Then check in all the Eclipse project files (which is how Eclipse is designed to work). That way I get the Eclipse project configured exactly the right way and anyone else who checks it out can do so directly into Eclipse without any other steps.

With the Eclipse project configured as a Gradle project, I can easily update it if the dependencies are changed by right-click on project and choosing **Gradle** > **Update Dependencies** which just re-generates the dynamic Gradle classpath container without touching any of the Eclipse files.